# Change the color of the following Resharper's items in VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

Recently I've started using one of the Dainty VS themes( the Night Owl) i'm really happy with this theme so far, except for the colors for some Reshapre's items, I've changed some of them and some I can't find or I don't know the item name exactly!. Items i want to change their color are in the following image inside the red circles.

https://ibb.co/Ln1ZwSW "Reshaper items"

Thanks.

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but I have found JetBrain's support to be excellent. I would contact them if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color for the `ReSharper Debugger DataTips` item in `Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts & Colors`